# Joint Probability Distribution of the marginal gaussianization of a multivariate distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, joint-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution, copula

I have a set of random variables $Y = Y_1, \dots, Y_k$, where each $Y_i$ follows a gamma distribution. I would like to transform the variables into normally distributed variables.

Suppose I use a function  $\phi$ to **marginally** transform all $Y_i$ so that they follow a normal distribution, i.e. $$\phi: (Y_1, \dots, Y_k) \rightarrow (\phi_1(Y_1), \dots, \phi_k(Y_k)),$$

so that each $\phi_i \sim N(\mu_i, \sigma_i)$. Call $Z =(\phi_1(Y_1), \dots, \phi_k(Y_k))$.

Now I wonder about the relationship between the joint probability distribution of $Y$ and the joint probability distribution of $Z$. Is there any way to recover  the joint probability distribution of $Y$ from the joint probability distribution of $Z$? Maybe making some assumptions over $\phi$?

Comment: why are you doing this?

Comment: @Aksakal I am studying Latent Variable Models and I wonder about the relationship of the latent variable and the modeled variable in global terms, so I thought in the JPD.

Answer (score 2):

One way to transform is as follows.
Suppose gaussian CDF is $F$ and Gamma CDF is $\Gamma$. 
$$Z_i=F^{-1}_i(\Gamma_i(Y_i))$$
If you do it this way the converting back to Gamma is straightforward, and the correlation structure will be preserved in the following sense:
$$C=cov[\Gamma(Y)]=cov[F(Z)]$$

Comment: Why does this *nonlinear* transformation preserve correlations?  (I doubt it does.)

Comment: @whuber, correlation in certain way, i.e. uniforms formed by CDF

Comment: I see now.  It's hard to decide whether that's a clever or trivial observation, but maybe it's both ;-).  (+1)

Comment: @Aksakal I think you meant "converting back to Gaussian" -> " converting back to Gamma"?

Comment: @Aksakal Also, I think the first formula should be $Z_i=F^{-1}_i(\Gamma_i(Y_i))$

Comment: @D1X, yeah, I mixed them up